# Google User Administration with Google Admin SDK, vb.net and service account working in development but not production

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I need to use the Google Admin  SDK Directory Service to add users to our gsuite domain, I am using a service account and language is vb.net. My application works great in visual studio, but as soon as I publish it to my IIS server I get crickets.
I am at a loss and have been struggling with this off and on for months.  I contacted google cloud support and they thought my code looked ok to them but couldn't help with specific coding issues.  They referred me here.
So here is my code

```
Try
    ' service account email address
    Const serviceAccount As String = "My service account"

    ' import service account key p12 certificate.
      
    Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2("c:\googletest\accountmgmt-************.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
                
    ' G Suite user email address
    Dim gsuiteUser = "My Superadmin Account"

    Dim serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount) With {
            .User = gsuiteUser,
            .Scopes = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"}
        }.FromCertificate(certificate)

   
    ' request access token
    Dim credential = New ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer)
    If Not credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result Then 
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Access token failed.")
    End If
    Dim service = New DirectoryService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
                .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                .ApplicationName = "AccountMgmt"
            })
    
    Dim user As User = New User()
    Dim Name As UserName = New UserName
    Name.FamilyName = "Testy"
    Name.GivenName = "Test1"
    user.Name = Name
    user.Password = "Password123!"
    user.PrimaryEmail = "ttesty@mydomain.com"
    Dim results As User = service.Users.Insert(user).Execute()
       

Catch ep As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString())
End Try
```

As I said it works fine on my development box  in visual studio but when I publish it to my IIS server and execute it I get no indication it does anything and the account is not created.  Any suggestions either in vb.net or c#.net would be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are trying to load the certificate using system path "c:..." Most likely this will return IO error. Try changing the path to "Server.MapPath()" to load the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for replying Majdi,  I tried your suggestion, thought it made good sense, Again it worked on my development box but not from my web server.  Made sure permissions were set on the file as well.  Still at a loss as to why this doesn't work.